# If you set the font-family to only sans-serif what is the font order?

Tags: css

I tried googling this but couldn't find an answer, I know Arial comes first...

Also, I've seen people do

```
font-family: sans-serif, arial, 2nd font in sans-serif, 3rd font in sans-serif...
```

Where it seems that after sans-serif, they're listing all the fonts in that family in the respective order.  Isn't that unnecessary work since sans-serif is the catch-all for that group of fonts in that order?

Comment: I think You are right. "sans-serif" will prevent any other font families from being used.

Comment: Just because you see something... doesn't mean the people doing it have any clue. This seems to be particularly true with web development.

Comment: @mrtsherman I firebugged wikipedia and it lists the computer font for the text of the article as `sans-serif`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using sans-serif, its just dumb to list backups for it because they won't be used. Wikipedia appropriately applies their fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop):

> Generic font families are a fallback mechanism, a means of preserving
>   some of the style sheet author's intent in the worst case when none of
>   the specified fonts can be selected. For optimum typographic control,
>   particular named fonts should be used in style sheets.

Fonts should be listed in the order you would like them used, then the browser will attempt to apply them in order, proceeding through the list as needed when it cannot match a font on the user's system.

So it really makes no sense to list fallback fonts first as they would be applied before a non-generic font family rendering fonts like (in your example) Arial to be ignored and sans-serif top be applied. It's the same as just using `font-family: sans-serif;`.

Answer (score 2):

"I know Arial comes first..."

This is certainly not true in the general case. I mean, you cannot count on this being true for all clients.

You're perhaps thinking along the lines that Arial would be the first choice on Windows 7 in certain locales by default. But it won't be true for Linux. It won't necessarily be true even for all Windows users depending on how they have configured things. It's not possible for you to know what fonts will be used by the client. You can make some reasonable guess if you know a lot about your clients... but you would have to specify more detail about what your clients are expected to be.

But you're right about sans-serif being a catch-all. It's common to put that at the end of the list. I haven't seen it at the start. It doesn't make sense to list more things after it.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to suspect, and as other answers say, lists like `sans-serif, arial` are usually based on misunderstandings. But the situation is more complex.

According to the CSS 2.1 specification, “All five generic font families are defined to exist in all CSS implementations (they need not necessarily map to five distinct actual fonts).” However, it seems to me that my Firefox 10 violates this: it ignores the name `fantasy` so that `font-family: fantasy, xxx` results in `xxx` being used.

A more fundamental issue is that the specification requires that font selection be made on a per-character basis, and modern browsers generally implement this. Thus, for example, even in conforming implementations, the following usually causes the font listed after the generic name to be used for the special character, if that font is available on the system:

```
<style>
p.foo {  font-family: sans-serif, Arial Unicode MS; }
p.bar {  font-family: sans-serif, Lucida Sans Unicode; }
</style>
<p class=foo>Special: &#x2074;
<p class=bar>Special: &#x2074;
```

If the font corresponding to the generic name `sans-serif` contains the superscript four character (⁴) U+2074, then that font is used for it, of course, and here is no rendering difference for the two paragraphs. But it probably doesn’t. That font is probably Arial, Helvetica, or some other sans serif font with relatively small character repertoire. This implies that a browser will, for the special character, use the rest of the `font-family` list.

If you are using a Windows system with Office installed, you will most probably see two different glyphs for the superscript four character – unless you have configured your browser so that `sans-serif` is mapped to a font that contains it.